# Change the return key as 'Continue'

Tags: iphone, swift, keyboard, xcode6, custom-keyboard

I want to change the 'return' key of iphone virtual key to a completely customized name such as "Continue" instead of "Done". Can we do it? If yes then how? Can I remove the smily button which is marked in red rectangle.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't edit the keys like you want in your question. You can choose from some different types of Button-styles for your return-key but you can't change the text of it or remove keys. This keyboard is given and can't be changed.

If you want to do such kind of changes you will need to create your own [Custom Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html).